# I added some legs to a Blender model and now the bones do not move the mesh, what did I do?

Tags: armature

So this is the first time I've done this in Blender opposed to using PMX Editor. I wanted a model to have legs and a skirt instead of the jeans she originally had so I added them and removed the bones that came with the legs. I have deleted the extra vertex groups it created and now none of the bones work.

How do I go about fixing this? I have included the Blender file. Any help would be absolutely amazing.

[image]

Comment: Try turning [manipulate center points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/manipulate_center_points.html) off.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @batFINGER.

> Try turning manipulate center points off. – batFINGER